# Select records with datetime within next hour

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to retrieve records that have a scheduled time within an hour from now so that I can notify of upcoming appointments.

The following code is what I have tried but is not returning any records.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT $columns FROM $table WHERE scheduled
        BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) ORDER BY id DESC");
```

Comment: Should that be `DATE_ADD()` and not `DATE_SUB`?

Comment: Here's something to think about: `SELECT 2 BETWEEN 3 AND 1`

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is in question itself.

```
 DATE_ADD
```

Should be used instead of DATE_SUB. Since you're looking for data from future, date_add should give you values from future.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT $columns FROM $table WHERE scheduled
         < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL +1 HOUR) ORDER BY id DESC");
```

I think this way it could be worth